# MVC3 Recommended Controller, Action query re-use

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In an MVC3 app what is the recommended method to store the Controller, Action & query details of a page and then re-use them in an actionlink on a subsequent page?

e.g. from page ~/Home/BlogsByTag?tag=Cloud%20Services listing a series of blogs, what is the 'best' way to capture the Controller, Action & query and then how can these then be applied to a 'Back to List' actionlink in a subsequent edit page (~/Admin/Edit/?Blog=1234)?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you want to generate an ActionLink with the url from the referring page?

You can read the referrer from the request in terms of a complete url:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

If you want to have access to the action, controller and query parts, you have to pass them in the link as parameters. For example:

```
Html.ActionLink("Linktext", "Edit", "Admin", null, 
                               new {
                                  Blog = 1234, 
                                  ReferringController = "Home",
                                  ReferringAction = "BlogsByTag",
                                  ReferringQueryParams = ...
                               });
```

Then you can read that vals in the Edit Action and pass it to the View to generate the back-link.

But maybe using `history.back()` is a simpler approach.

Comment: I want the actionlink to cause a return to ~/Home/BlogsByTag?tag=Cloud%20Services from subsequent pages that might not have this page as the referrer.

Comment: Ok, the question is, where do you want to code that values? My second approach will send the values from the *referring* page via url parameters because you wrote *re-use them in an actionlink on a subsequent page*

Comment: From the original page (~/Home/BlogsByTag?tag=Cloud%20Services) containing a list of blogs, I want to progress to a details page for a selected blog and then on to further pages e.g. editing and/or delete confirmation pages. It is on these pages that I want the actionlink to be able to link back to the original page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Url.RouteCollection["controller"]
Url.RouteCollection["action"]
...
```

For the variables you need. For the querystring you can use:

Request.QueryString["variable1"]

Alternatively you can declare the controller:

```
public ActionResult MyController(string controller, string action, string variable...)
```

and the variables will be automagically filled.

Then you can store this info (or the full url) on `Session["refurl"]` for example, which is valid for the rest of the user's session

Comment: If I store the values in Session variables what will the actionlink construction look like?